# Snmp Server for Windows

Tags: windows, snmp

I'm looking for a snmp server for windows, are there any free (or at least working trial version) ones, I can only find clients?

I know I could install the windows snmp service but here at work it is not really an option (I don't have the "win xp" CD needed and support is as complicated as slow, even worse, it's Friday).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) software contains both clients and servers.  Specifically, the project contains both an SNMP agent server than runs on windows, as well as a trap receiver application as well.

Comment: FYI Net-SNMP is still an active project with some recent commits! They also have a large tutorials section. http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials

Comment: It's definitely still active :-)  I just pushed a new beta release a week ago, and have many more planned (we have multiple active branches).